# Gmail can't authenticate Office 365 Address via SMTP

Tags: gmail, smtp, microsoft-outlook-365

- Custom Domain registered through GoDaddy
- Office 365 email purchased through GoDaddy
- Trying to send / receive email for this address using free Gmail (not G suite)

I have reviewed every resource I can find for the issue and tried all solutions multiple times and contacted GoDaddy who have me the same information. I have previously used this system for other custom domains (not Office 365) with no issues. To confirm:
 - I have enabled POP and IMAP in Gmail
 - I have "allowed less secure apps" in Google Account
 - I have verified my auth credentials 100 times in Office 365

**Step 1:**
Added new email in gmail to RECEIVE mail (POP) with no issue at all using the following credentials:

- email address: info@customdomain.com
- user: info@customdomain.com
- pass: xxxxxxxxx
- server: outlook.office365.com
- port: 995
- Use SSL option selected

[image]

**Step 2:**
Added email in gmail to SEND emails (SMTP) with the same credentials and it failed:

- email address: info@customdomain.com
- user: info@customdomain.com
- pass: xxxxxxxxx
- server: smtp.office365.com
- port: 587
- Secured Connection using TLS

[image]

I don't know enough about the technical aspects of this process to know what else may be interfering with the process. Is this a new limitation set on free Gmail accounts?